# Codeignter's image manipulation(using GD library) doesn't resize some JPEG images

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, image-processing, file-upload

I have an upload form that takes an image jpg/gif/etc, I use it to upload some images(image format is Jpg) for the gallery I use for my website, but unfortunately it doesn't work well for some images(It makes everything black and in the upper left corner(0, 0) it shows the resized images).
I tried resizing the images online and it works with no problem , So I think the problem is not with the image itself, It is in the library/configuration.

My upload AND resize image handler code:

```
 function upload() {
        //check if admin is logged in.
        if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged') == 1) {
            //loading the configuration for the upload library.
            $config = array();
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '7000';
            $config['max_width'] = '6000';
            $config['max_height'] = '5000';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
                $data['redirect_msg'] = $this->upload->display_errors() . '<br /> go back to ' . anchor('admin/', 'main page');
                $this->load->view('redirect', $data);
            } else {
                //getting the image's information, in order to resize it.
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $image_path = $upload_data['full_path'];

                /* loading the configuration for the image manuiplation library. */
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd';
                $config['source_image'] = $image_path;
                $config['width'] = '800';
                $config['height'] = '600';
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE; //tried setting it to TRUE aswell.
                //loading the library
                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                //starting the resize proccess.
                $this->image_lib->resize();
                //checking if the is an error in the resizing proccess.
                if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                    /* displaying the errors */
                    $data['redirect_msg'] = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                    $this->load->view('redirect', $data);
                } else {
                    /* show positive message. */
                    $data['redirect_msg'] = 'Upload successful!<br />redirecting to ' . anchor('admin/', 'homepage') . ' in 3 seconds';
                    $this->load->view('redirect', $data);
                    //saving the image name to a database table, so we can retrieve it when needed(for the slideshow).
                    $this->db_model->save_image($upload_data['orig_name']);
                    //doing the redirect.
                    header('refresh:3;url=' . site_url('admin/'));
                }
            }
        } else { //if not logged in, show negative message.
            $data['redirect_msg'] = 'you are not logged in. < br/> login ' . anchor('admin/', 'here');
            $this->load->view('redirect', $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you try with image_library gd2?

Comment: @Kokers Yes, I tried using it. same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resizing that image two times:

```
//starting the resize proccess.
$this->image_lib->resize();
    //checking if the is an error in the resizing proccess.
    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
```

just do it once:

```
//starting the resize proccess.            
//checking if the is an error in the resizing proccess.
            if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
```